# How to determine cursor visibility for a thread in Win32?

Tags: winapi

Each thread have their own cursor count that is incremented/decremented by ShowCursor calls.
Is there a way to query that counter to determine if the cursor is currently visible?

This pattern is supposed to work but there are some problems with that:

```
ShowCursor (FALSE);
bool visible = (ShowCursor (TRUE) >= 0);
```

- The windows app compatibility layer might silently not allow the counter to decrease below 0 so the first ShowCursor call does nothing and the second corrupts the counter.
- It has some unwanted side effects like potential and needless cursor hiding/unhiding

Comment: "*The windows app compatibility layer might silently not allow the counter to decrease below 0*" - doubtful since [negative values are valid](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091217-00/?p=15643). "*unwanted side effects like potential and needless cursor/unhiding*" - maybe, but it would likely be too quick to really notice. If course, there is always `WM_SETREDRAW` and `LockWindowUpdate()`.

Comment: "doubtful since negative values are valid."

Yes, but there are some (old) games where the built-in compat layer doesn't allow to hide the cursor for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

You can test for cursor visibility directly with GetCursorInfo()

```
bool IsCursorVisible()
{
    CURSORINFO ci = { sizeof(CURSORINFO) };
    if (GetCursorInfo(&ci))
        return ci.flags & CURSOR_SHOWING;
    return false;
}
```

I'm not sure what it means for this call to fail so I just have it returning false if it fails.

Comment: This is even stated in the [ShowCursor()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showcursor) documentation: "*Call [GetCursorInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcursorinfo) to determine the cursor visibility.*"

Comment: GetCursorInfo gives back the state of the 'global' cursor.
So that, wherever the cursor is on the screen, you get its state.
But ShowCursor handles a per-thread count which affect windows created from the particular thread.

Comment: yes but isn't what is ultimately important whether the cursor on the screen or not. Per-thread visibility counts are an implementation detail. I guess I do not understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Anyway, thx for the reply!
I think I should get the global position by GetCursorInfo, then determine if the cursor is above one of my windows (by WindowFromPoint). If it is, then I can use the result flag from GetCursorInfo.